# how to inserted right button image programmatically UINavigation bar swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to override programmatically the rightButton of a navigation item with a static image

**Button like this:**

[image]

I have tried a lot of time to solve it but yet not get proper answer.

Can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: If you push a viewcontroller from One to another. that left bar button image appear default. You need to set left bar button programmatically and set image for bar button for solve this issue.

Comment: @NitinGohel left != right ;)

Comment: Please show the code what you have tried.

Comment: as in image its look like he is asking about left bar button. if that image setting from storyboard then he can easily set and replace by xib or storyboard.

Comment: i already create right bar button programmatically and set image for bar button but image aligment and x and y not set properly - nitin Gohel

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution. You could create extension to UIBarButton item.
Example:

```
import UIKit

    extension UIBarButtonItem {

        convenience init (image: UIImage?, target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 44.0, height: 44.0)
            button.addTarget(target, action: action!, for: .touchUpInside)
            button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 7.0)

            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
                button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
            }
            self.init(customView: button)
        }
    }
```

And then use it like that in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "example"), target: self, action: #selector(exampleAction(sender:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Comment: I create UIBar RightButton insite viewWillApear method whenever i use your code on that but does not work

Comment: You should do it only once in viewDidLoad. What is the problem? Button is not visible?

Comment: Are you sure that image have correct name? Could you show your code?

Comment: tell me one thing what can i use replace #selector(exampleAction(sender:)))  ??

Comment: Yes of course, you should put there your action method for this button.

Comment: That's strange. It would be much easier for me to help you if you'd share code snippet of your Controller.

Comment: nothing diffrent of my code i simply add extension of my class and your 2 lines code inside my viewdidload

Comment: How did you create title on your navigation bar? Maybe that button is actually created but is behind your title label? You should definitely check that in a view debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing `UIBarButtonItem` convenience `init` method:

```
convenience init(image: UIImage?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, target: Any?, action: Selector?)
```

With `style` = .plain (no border).

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617163-init

Then, to inform your UINavigationController to show your buttons when your UIViewController in the the top of the navigation stack, set the `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` property of your view controller:

```
(myViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [<your items>]
```